# Run a SSIS Package outside of SSDT (2017)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have searched multiple forums and found question similar, but doesn't match my environments.

Problem: Cannot execute a package within a package

> Error: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install st_Check_Files of Integration Services or higher.

SQL Server 2017 info

[image: SQL Server 2017 info]

SSMS info

[image: SSMS info]

Versions inside Visual Studio 2017

[image: Versions inside Visual Studio 2017]

Previously, I could not execute ANY packages with dtexec from command prompt, or execute any packages from within SQL Server Agent.

I uninstalled any remnants of SQL server as well as SSIS and SSDT and reinstalled 2017 versions of both and now I CAN execute via dtexec command prompt and SQL Server but cannot execute within Visual Studio SSDT (2017).

Any further insight?

Comment: FYI My SSDT about box looks exactly the same with regards to SQL Server  Integration Services: there's nothing after the dash, but in the produce details I have the same version. My version of SSDT is 15.5.6 though. I think you are going to need to expand on 'cannot' - do you get an error?

Comment: sorry, my error: came inline with the problem. edited to fix

Comment: So that error appears when you try and execute run in SSDT? and this happens when you right click / execute that package? I don't know if I will be able to help but I can certainly assist in getting you to completely describe your issue.

Comment: If I execute the master package, the one that launches the "execute package task"  (from file system), I get this error. If I launch that sub package as a stand-alone it runs fine.

Comment: I would add that these packages were imported from a SQL 2012 instance

Comment: Is there some kind of 'in-process' tick in the execute package task? Fiddle with that (just to isolate the error). I believe the error you're seeing is because it's confused about your install. Did you ever install an Express version of SQL Server? Not sure how to fix it unfortunately.

Comment: So I was able to resolve the issue by changing the target from SQL 2012 to 2017. Now, executing packages with script tasks in them from sql agent throws compile errors until I open the package/script and save it again (no changes).

Comment: You should enter that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve the issue by changing the target from SQL 2012 to 2017. Now, executing packages with script tasks in them from sql agent throws compile errors until I open the package/script and save it again (no changes).